# SQL Access Criteria Exclusions

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to develop a `combobox` based on a query. The query excludes a staff member if the date of the appointment is the same as a date they are scheduled to be absent. The statement only runs if it's a particular type of appointment called `"Per Session"`. 
So If it's a "perSession" Appointment Query all the staff members who are available on the appointment date. Else Show all staff members.

`IIf([Forms]![Scheduling]![ApptType]="PerSession",Not (([Staff].[ABS Date1])=("#" & [Forms]![Scheduling]![EvalDate] & "#")),([Staff].[ABS Date1]) Like "*") Or Is Null`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Whats is `[Staff]` here? May be you are missing `[Forms]!` afte `Not` and before `(([Staff].....`

Comment: [Staff] is a table of staff members added unrelated in the query GUI. [ABS Date1] is a single date they will be absent, it is a date field. However, I'd like this to be a text field which can hold multiple dates separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

In experimentation I found the issue was with the designer. The Designer assumes the Where criteria field in the column will equal the result of the Iif statement. However I was working to not equal if true and equal if not true. By using the SQL view I was able to write the Iif statement to evaluate the proper SQL. 
See below. 
(IIf([Forms]![Scheduling]![ApptType]="PerSession",(([Staff].[ABS Date1])<>[Forms]![Scheduling]![EvalDate]) OR ([Staff].[ABS Date1]) Is Null ,([Staff].[ABS Date1]) Like "*" OR ([Staff].[ABS Date1]) Is Null)))